# Spring MVC response on AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Suppose there is a REST API to login:

```
/api/user/login
```

In spring security, it is easy to replace HTTP entry point/success handler/failure handler as follow

```
<http 
    pattern="/**" 
    use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <form-login
        authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"
        login-processing-url="/api/user/login"
        username-parameter="login"
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout 
        invalidate-session="true" 
        delete-cookies="WSESSIONID" 
        logout-url="/api/user/logout"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
    ....
</http>
```

and generate a custom response on success/fail status:

```
public class RestUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getOutputStream().write("success".getBytes());
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

I`m looking for a way to return an object the same as Spring MVC controllers in both success and fail status. In this case the response encoding must be the same as MVC controllers and considers Accept from request header.

Comment: May I ask why you need that?

Comment: It is a RESTFull service and the success result is user detail. In the other hand failure result is a business exception. Client may want JSON/XML as result.

Comment: Why don't you "return the object" in the LoginController?

Comment: I use Spring security filter and authentication process is not part of Spring MVC.

Comment: Why not just define a class, define a method that takes the parameters you require, and call that method before the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` or `onAuthenticationFailure()` exits?